# Passing structure as pointer

Tags: c

I'm trying to pass structure as pointer in function arguments. Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    int yearOfManufacture;
    char model[50];
    bool gasoline;
} Car;


void PrintCarDetails(Car details);

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{        
    Car ford;
    ford.yearOfManufacture = 1997;
    ford.gasoline = true;
    strcpy(ford.model, "Focus");

    PrintCarDetails(&ford);

     return 0;
}

void PrintCarDetails(Car *details)
{
    printf("Car model %s", details->model);
}
```

I get an error "Passing Car to parameter of incompatible type Car. What I miss ?

Comment: Hint: a function definition also serves as prototype, provided you define it before you use it. So, if you write `main` at the bottom of the file, you can leave out the prototype. *some people don't like `main` at the bottom; some people don't like it at the top; lol*

Comment: @pmg I would argue that the practical benefit not having to write any more prototypes than absolutely necessary (I mean, in how many languages commonly used today are they **ever** needed?) should trump any aesthetic preference for ordering of functions. DRY, and all that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Forward declaration should be :

```
void PrintCarDetails(Car * details);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
void PrintCarDetails(Car *details);
```

```
*
```

is missing in the forward declaration.

Answer (score 3):

The function definition differs from the function declaration. In the declaration you state that a a Car struct should be used as an argument, but in the definition you want a pointer to a Car struct.

Answer (score 3):

You probably misspinted declaration of PrintCarDetails function.
Should be:

```
void PrintCarDetails(Car *details);
```

works [here](http://codepad.org/4MQgcmy7)

Answer (score 0):

It is just a little mistake, your function definition and declaration don't match:

- line 12 : `void PrintCarDetails(Car details);`
- line 26 : `void PrintCarDetails(Car *details);`

just fix the line 12 with : `void PrintCarDetails(Car *details);`